# Trying to have a better understanding of classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
from enum import Enum, auto
import random
class Numeri(Enum):
    Zero = 0
    One = 1
    Two = 2
    Three = auto()
    Four = auto()

class Nome_numeri(Enum):
    Zero = "Zero"
    One = "One"
    Two = "Two"
    Three = "Three"
    Four = "Four"

class Prova_numeri:
    def __init__(self, numeri: Numeri, nome_numeri: Nome_numeri) -> None:
        self.numeri = numeri
        self.nome_numeri = nome_numeri
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.numeri.value} = {self.nome_numeri.value}"
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.numeri.value} = {self.nome_numeri.value}"
    
def start():
    all_numbers = [Prova_numeri(numeri, nome_numeri) for numeri in Numeri for nome_numeri in Nome_numeri]
    unique_numbers_set = set()
    while len(unique_numbers_set) < 5:
        new_number = random.choice(all_numbers)
        unique_numbers_set.add(new_number)
    unique_numbers = list(unique_numbers_set)
    sorted_numbers = sorted(unique_numbers, key=lambda x: x.numeri.value)
    print("Numbers from 0 to 4:", ", ".join(str(number) for number in sorted_numbers))

start()
```

I'm doing some tries to have a better understanding of classes, but I'm not figuring out what I'm doing wrong. The terminal is continuosly printing random numbers name and values. Ex:  Numbers from 0 to 4: 0 = Two, 3 = One, 1 = Four.....

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Have you looked at `all_numbers`? It's the cartesian product of all the names and numbers, you didn't pair the corresponding elements. Use `zip(Numeri, Nome_numeri)` to get the corresponding pairs.